# Element called "Likert" - Result showing wrong data

Tags: webforms

I'm building a survey using the Webforms module. And, I was trying to use the Element called "Likert". I had some problems displaying the value of the field. After submitting a simple form, I get a value word "Strongly Disagree" rather than the value "1".

https://ibb.co/jE9ZFG

https://ibb.co/jqhzhw

Any advise,

Comment: After I submit data into my webform survey, I found that the value from the element>types : Likert" works fine returning the right data which is numeric like this image. https://ibb.co/gnQV9m
However, when I try to download (https://ibb.co/m6AV9m) the information in excel, it returns this information: https://ibb.co/mTPJvR  This is not right! Have any of you had a problem like this before? I tried to modify the setting but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Likerts and all options based elements show the label/text and not the submitted value by default. You can display the 'raw' value by changing the element's 'Submission Display' under the 'Advanced' tab in the element's edit dialog.[image]

Comment: Thank you! it works.Sorry for bothering you; I wondered about the total # of words under GENERAL option "OPTION TEXT" I can't get more than 35 words.

Comment: I select "Raw value" shows this https://ibb.co/jHaxkG. Next, I download the data in excel and is not showing out that field. But, I can see it under "submissions page displays".

Comment: Options Text is limited to 255 characters.  I think we need to increase that limit. Please create a ticket in the Webform module's issue queue.

Comment: Hello again, I can't make it to work. The image here G12: https://ibb.co/ixdVaR shows the whole text but not the value "1" or "2". I selected "Raw Value" & it'sn't working. It works in my first forms above but not in here. Any advise about it.

Comment: Here is the YAML code: https://ibb.co/fomf9m

Comment: You should create a ticket in the webform module's issue queue.
https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/webform?version=8.x